# Android Keyboard is not showing on webview's textbox onfocus

Tags: android, android-webview, android-keypad

In my application, the android **keyboard is not shown in the webview's textbox onfocus**. Is there any restrictions for this?. I have tried **webview.requestFocus()** method in the webview touchlistener. But the textbox is always focus, the keyboard is not at all shown.

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
            v.requestFocus();
        }
        break;
}
return false;
```

}

I have set this listener in oncreate method as **webview.setOnTouchListener(this);**

How can I resolve this issue.?

Comment: are u using in emulator or phone

Comment: I am using phone Android 2.2, 4.0.4 and 4.1.2.

Comment: webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN); try this

Comment: Already I tried this method, the textbox is in onfucus, but the keyboard is not shown. If I am clicking textbox once again the keyboard is shown.

Comment: Just to be sure, This happens in all android version you tested on right? (Including ICS and up)

Comment: Yes. I have tested the code in oncreate of the webview and after loading the url into the webview.

Comment: Dude I feel your pain, I too use webview and it's the glicthes thing. I have focus issues and sometimes the keyboard loses it after you input something. I think it's because of the android browser. If it used Chrome engine, there would be lot less problems. I have tried the same codes you have and helps a little but not completely. Seems more problematic versions < 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it like this in my onCreate and this seems to fix it.
It's basically the same code you have but with the `_webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);` call added before setting the onTouchListener.

```
    _webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    _webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to open the keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) cntx
                .getSystemService(cntx.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(
                view.getApplicationWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        view.requestFocus();
```